# How can i verify query string sent from another website on my website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a website that connect to an API which requires that I generate a reference code along with other information i will need to complete my registration. After the registration has been confirmed  the server will respond with a redirect to my controller action to complete the whole process where I have to verify same with another controller action. However, I have tried the following but still have some difficulty making my website respond to the redirect ie: showing a message 'book confirmed!'

```
Here is the url i get: 
  http/example.com/?ref=2755558333388=referencecode=2755558333388
instead of        
  http/example.com/book?ref=2755558333388=referencecode=2755558333388



# route
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   get 'confirmations/register'
   post 'confirmations/verified'
end


# controller:

class ConfirmationsController < ApplicationController
  def register
    registerationObj = Registration.new(ENV["BOOKREG_PUBLIC_KEY"], ENV["BOOKREG_PRIVATE_KEY"])
    book = RegistrationBooks.new(registrationObj)
    :action = books.create(
        :book_title => @book.title,
        :phone => current_user.phone,
        :email => current_user.email,
        :referencecode => @book.referencecode
  end

  def verified
    if params[:referencecode == @book.referencecode
      flash[:alert] = "Your book has been verified"
      redirect_to books_path
    else
      redirect_to current_user_edit_path, notice: "Sorry your book was not verified"
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why do you expect the redirect to be to `/verified` and not to `/`? Did you configure that when using that API? or did the API documentation says that? I mean, you say you have some url instead of another url but you gave no indication on why it should be that way. From your routes you are even expecting the path to be `/confirmations/verified`, not just `verified`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the documentation says it will append the query string on the call_back parameter in which case: www.example.com/books/?ref=2755558333388=referencecode=2755558333388. Thanks

Comment: What's "the call_back parameter"? I don't see any parameter named `call_back` or similar on your code. Where do you tell the API that you expect the redirect to be at /verified (since you expect it to be that url, why do you expect that?)?

Comment: Pls, @arieljuod is there a way I can add a call_back to the controller to respond to the redirect from the api sever such that it redirects to 'verified' action? if there is, please help

Comment: @arieljuod thanks, your questions helped me. I was able to figure out that i did not configure the callback url correctly on the api. instead of providing 'https//example.com/confirmations/verified', i provided 'https//example.com/' Thanks a lot, cheers!